# Adding Empty Space to End of ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView that with alphabetical headers for each letter.  I also have an index function that brings the letter headers to the top of the screen.

My problem is when I reach the end of the list setSelection is unable to bring the last few headers to the top because it will not scroll past the end of the list.

My question is this:  Is there a way to add a blank space to the end of the screen dependent on screen size?  I would like to scroll until the  last item in the list is at the top of the listView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using an extension of `BaseAdapter` to populate your ListView?

There may be a built-in way to do what you are asking, but I don't know of one.  If you end up creating it yourself, how about this approach:

- Return `list.size() + EXTRA` in `getCount()`
- Modify `getItem()` to return something sane if it asks for an item not in your list
- Modify `getView()` to configure the given view as a simple horizontal padding with the same height as the rest of your views if the `position` index is more than your list size

You would need to fiddle around with the `EXTRA` constant to see what value is best.

Comment: I disagree, @Shayan_Aryan this answer perfectly helped me to figure what to do in a matter of 30 seconds :)

Comment: only in case of using BaseAdapter, though responsibility to provide full info lays on the person asking a question, and he did not specify what he used, so it's a valid answer

Answer (score 89):

The easiest way to add space is to add padding in xml and set `clipToPadding:"false"`.

#### For `RecyclerView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

#### For `ListView`

```
<ListView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

#### And same goes for the `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

This specifically adds the blank space to top and bottom but hide the space when you scroll the view.

Comment: This must be as Accepted Answer. (y)

Comment: Don't forget to add `android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"` so your scrollbar doesn't stay inside the padding

Comment: But the problem is the scrolling feature is gone, the screen becomes total blank (I set android:paddingBottom="800dp") and the listview is gone.

Comment: @LoganGuo for that dynamically add a item in your list at 1 position ,
in padding scroll doesn't work

Comment: Best answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13366310/2529315 with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14560982/2529315

Answer (score 5):

Try the followings:

```
View footer = new View(getActivity());
footer.setLayoutParams( new AbsListView.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 100 ));
mListView.addFooterView(footer, null, false);
```

Comment: what a tragedy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366281/how-can-i-add-blank-space-to-the-end-of-a-listview same answer with 2 downvotes

Comment: Best answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13366310/2529315 with http://stackoverflow.com/a/14560982/2529315