# Is it safe to use .getWidth on Display even though its deprecated

Tags: android, width, deprecated

So i have a small problem, i'm writing a function which need to send screen width to server. I got it all to work, and i use:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
```

to get width. However .getWidht() function is deprecated and it says u need to use:

```
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
```

But that function is only avaible for api level 13 or more, and my minimum sdk is 8. So what can i do? Is it safe if i stay with getWidth? Why adding new function and not make them backward compatible?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

May be this approach will be helpful:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
mContext.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: `getDefaultDisplay` is deprecated

Comment: we can use `WindowManager.currentWindowMetrics.bounds` for 30+ API

Answer (score 11):

You can check for API level at runtime, and choose which to use, e.g.:

```
final int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
final int width;
if (version >= 13)
{
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    width = size.x;
}
else
{
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    width = display.getWidth();
}
```

Comment: hmm sounds ok, but steal is it fine if i only use getwidth?

Comment: Yes, if it's not available on older versions then you've got no option.

Comment: you can do fine enough with getWidth() in most cases.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the latest Code without Deprecation.

**Kotlin**

```
 val metrics: DisplayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
 val width = metrics.widthPixels
```

**Java**

```
  DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
  int width = metrics.widthPixels;
  int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be correct, use this approach:

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
} else {
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
}
```

Comment: You're comparing an int against a String (VERSION.RELEASE) there.

Comment: If you wanted to be correct you wouldn't compare an int to a String and you wouldn't store the int in a non final local variable, hell you don't even need that variable, why store it in the 1st place. ;) You proably want to do `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {`

Comment: display.getSize is also deprecated